# map(arcpy.AddError, traceback.format_exc().split("\n"))

Tags: python, arcpy

What does this expression mean? I see this in many python scripts.

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    map(arcpy.AddError, traceback.format_exc().split("\n"))
    arcpy.AddError(str(e))
```

traceback.format_exc().split("\n") returns ['None','']

Comment: I have an answer explaining the map portion, but it seems like an error with the traceback if it returns `['None', '']` or no error at all?? In the latter case, the exception wouldn't be called in the first place.  That seems strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is calling on the [built in map function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), which takes a function as the first argument (arcpy.AddError) and telling it to call AddError for every piece of the message split by a new line character.  So for example, if the traceback message was this:

```
Error Reading File:
  File is of the wrong type
  Needs to be CSV file
```

the raw string would be:

`"ErrorError Reading File:\n  File is of the wrong type\n  Needs to be CSV file"`

So this:

`map(arcpy.AddError, traceback.format_exc().split("\n"))`

is the exact same as:

```
arcpy.AddError('Error Reading File:')
arcpy.AddError('  File is of the wrong type')
arcpy.AddError('  Needs to be CSV file')
```